# extract a zip file with digit code password in python

Tags: python, zip

I am doing challenges and this come up: we've started organising the files to try and make sense of them, but they're all locked with a numerical three-digit passcode. See if you can write a script to get into this example file alien-zip-2092.zip and read the text file inside which we think is named whatever the zip is (so in this case alien-zip-2092.txt). Oh, by the way, files should be extracted to the /tmp/ directory.

**Extract the file to the /tmp/ directory to get the flag. Make sure to break out of the loop when you hit the correct password, otherwise you will override the correct file with a blank one with the same name.**

```
import zipfile as zip
filename = "file alien-zip-2092.zip"
zip.filename.extractall(psw=111)
```

this is what i did but did not work I thing there is another way.

Comment: `zip.filename.extractall(psw="111")` is already better. Password is a string, not a number

Comment: You're not likely to get any good answers with this post as it is currently written; it _looks like_ the question you are asking is, "how do I beat this coding challenge?", and that in turn might be perceived as cheating. To get better help, you'll want to ask a more focused question about the problem you're having; see the site help page on [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, if you can, say something here about what isn't working (cryptic error message? file isn't readable? don't know how to detect when the extraction succeeds/fails?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `zipfile` module like this:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
ZipFile('alien-zip-2092.zip').extractall(path='/tmp', pwd='111')
```

Comment: I see. Can you try `path` as a keyword argument instead? I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
import zipfile
Z = zipfile.ZipFile("alien-zip-2092.zip")
PASS = bytes("111", 'utf-8')
Z.extractall(pwd=PASS)
```

Comment: doesn't work  forget the code I wrote and focus more on the question because I think my doesn't make any sense

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? It works correctly under Python 3.6. What error do you get?

Comment: error says PASS = bytes("111", 'utf-8')
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)